# Having problems with unity spread window on second click

Tags: 12.04, unity

I can´t spread window by click twice on the unity launcher after setting for something in ibus, and I am not sure is this a ibus problem.

Problem Reproduce Video (<1min): http://www.sendspace.com/file/wkt5n6

- Open some windows to check if spread window function works normally.
- Change some setting in ibus.
- Click on launcher.

Expected result: It works normally as the video shown.

Environment: Ubuntu 12.04, unity 5.14.0

*(Sorry for my bad English.)*

**== Edit ==**

It seems that spread window function won´t work when

```
Show language panel = Always
```

Comment: You've put some real work into that! This seems like a good bug report to me, and those should be filed on Launchpad.net and not here. We have a very powerful tool to file good bug reports. Press Alt+F2 and enter "ubuntu-bug unity". This will collect some information about your system and open your browser to the right page where you can enter information like you did above.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I have just reported it to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1035895 .

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). *This comment is for reference*